# Extjs checkbox selection issue

Tags: checkbox, extjs4

i am working in extjs4. i have grid with checkbox selection model. Grid is displaying files and folders. If folder get selected then i want to hide some menu. So have written code as-

```
selectionchange:function( model, selected, eOpts ){
                    var centralPanel = me.up();
                    var actionBtn = centralPanel.queryById('libraryactionBtn');
                    if(selected.length > 1) {   
                        actionBtn.show();
                        //var i=0;
                        for(i=0;i<selected.length;i++)
                            {
                            if(selected[i].data.isLeaf)
                                {
                                centralPanel.queryById('library-action-menu-view').hide();
                                centralPanel.queryById('library-action-menu-viewOrAddTag').hide();
                                centralPanel.queryById('library-action-menu-viewOrAddNotes').hide();
                                centralPanel.queryById('library-action-menu-copyToCompaign').hide();
                                centralPanel.queryById('library-action-menu-copyToProject').hide();
                                centralPanel.queryById('library-action-menu-sendLink').hide();
                                centralPanel.queryById('library-action-menu-addtofavorite').hide();
                                centralPanel.queryById('library-action-menu-downloadItem').hide();
                                }
                            }
                    } else {
                        actionBtn.hide();
                    }
```

where selected.data.isLeaf is false for folder. Its executing correctly only first time. Next time when i am selecting file,then also its hiding menu for file. And if folder is deselected then also its hiding menu. So what modifications i need to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all I don't see any code that shows the menu..You are just hiding the menu.

Secondly make sure selected[i].data.isLeaf is false and not "false".